# Enabling Tailwind Just-in-time (JIT) prevents build

Tags: vue.js, jit, tailwind-css

I have an issue deploying my VUE.js application including Tailwind's Just-in-time (JIT) engine. I followed Tailwind's official docs for Enabling JIT mode by updating its dependencies (tailwindcss, postcss and autoprefixer) to the latest versions. The issue is that I am able to build the app locally (by running `npm run build`) including JIT (`mode: "jit"`) in `tailwind.config.js` file as Tailwind describes in their docs but when I'm trying to build it inside the container the building gets stuck here

`=> => #  DONE  Build complete. The dist directory is ready to be deployed.`

`=> => #  INFO  Check out deployment instructions at https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html`

and doesn't proceed to deployment.

This only happens when I include `mode: "jit"` in `tailwind.config.js` file. If I remove it the problem goes away.

Any feedback would be highly appreciated.